# using filebeat with old version of logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I should send my logs to a logstash instance.

Unfortunately it's running a very old instance of logstash (that does not support beats input).

It has a normal tcp input like

```
     tcp {
        port => 8888
        codec => "json"
      }
```

This is the current configuration of filebeat

```
output.logastash:
    hosts: ["${LOGSTASH_HOST}:8888"]
```

Is there a way to configure filebeat so its output is accepted by logstash's tcp input?

Comment: what version of logstash?

Comment: logstash version 1.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, filebeat outputs using the beats protocol and will not work with a tcp input.

You have some options of how to work around this problem.

1. **Upgrade Logstash:** before I recommend any hacks or use of deprecated software, the best option is simply upgrading logstash to a modern version, there have been very few breaking changes and a lot of performance upgrades.
2. **Manually add the beats input to Logstash:** You can add the beats input to logstash 2.x with `/opt/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-beats`
3. **Use logstash-forwarder:** Filebeats' predecessor [logstash-forwarder](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder) is deprecated, but would work with the [lumberjack input of older logstashes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/1.5/plugins-inputs-lumberjack.html)
4. **Use an intermediary:** If we look at the [output options supported by filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-configuration-details.html) and the inputs supported by [Logstash >=1.5](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/1.5/input-plugins.html) you could use kafka or redis in between filebeat and logstash which they would both be compatible with.